# .outerHeight not accounting for padding

Tags: jquery, css

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KG3H8/4/

I have jquery expanding the height of my `.content`, which has a % based padding .

If I remove the padding it works perfectly.

I have updated the jsfiddle, placing `.outerHeight()` on everything but the `$(window)`, since it wouldn't work there anyway. I have also added printouts of the heights. I still cannot find the issue.

Comment: updated the fiddle to work , please check it before posting next time

Comment: Is it supposed to be like this? http://jsfiddle.net/KG3H8/1/ Your jQuery syntax seemed a bit wrong.

Comment: Yes my jquery was a bit off, sorry. Just quickly threw it in a fiddle so you wouldn't have to search the page. It still isn't accounting for the padding like it should.

Comment: I checked Jimjimmy's fiddle and i get the correct calculation on the content height... its not that outerHeight is miscalculating its that you have something thats generating extra space which you havent accounted for. I thought maybe it was the `:after` elements since they will generate a `line-box` but even after removing those its still off.

Comment: Please check the updated fiddle in the original post. I simplified it and added print outs of the integers jQuery returns. It acts like it's just ignoring the padding. I'm not sure what would be off, I just copied this from my site and stripped it down, only difference is no border/padding. I removed the padding and it works fine.. wasn't ideal but it works. I had to make another division inside of `.content` so I could pad that container. This is odd, but the answers probably ridiculously simple.

Answer (score 1):

[`outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) is supposed to include padding... and borders, and margins if you send `true` as the first parameter.

> Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements, including padding, border, and optionally margin. Returns an integer (without "px") representation of the value or null if called on an empty set of elements.

If thats not what you want then you probably want [`innerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/).

Comment: Indeed it is, but for some reason it isn't.. I understand it just prints an integer, that isn't the problem. It completely ignores the padding.

Comment: I thought the issue was that it was **including** the padding and you did not want that...